# NancyFX: How do I deserialize dynamic types via BrowserResponse.Body.DeserializeJson (unit tests)

Tags: json, unit-testing, nancy

I have the following NancyFX unit test. I use the [Shouldly](http://shouldly.github.com/) assertion library to give the set of extensions methods that start `.Should---`

```
[Fact]
public void Assessment__Should_return_assessment_state_for_specified_user()
{
    const AssessmentState assessmentState = AssessmentState.Passed;
    var user = Fake.Mentor();

    using (var db = Fake.Db())
    {
        db.Save(user);
        Fake.Assessment(user.Id, db, assessmentState);
        db.ClearStaleIndexes();
    }

    var response = Fake.Browser(user.UserName, user.Password)
            .Get("/assessment/state/" + user.Id, with => with.HttpRequest());

    //var result = (dynamic)body.DeserializeJson<ExpandoObject>();
    var result = (dynamic) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(response.Body.AsString());

    result.ShouldNotBe(null);
    ((AssessmentState) result.State).ShouldBe(assessmentState);
}
```

This test calls a `AssessmentService` uri defined as `/assessment/state/" + user.Id` which returns a simple JSON object definition that has a single property `State` of type (enum) `AssessmentState`, either `Passed`, `Failed` or `NotStarted`.

Here is the service handler so you can see there are no tricks.

```
Get["/assessment/state/{userid}"] = parameters =>
    {
        var assessment = AssessmentService.GetByUserId(Db, (string)parameters.userid);
        return assessment == null ? HttpStatusCode.NotFound : Response.AsJson(new
                                                                        {
                                                                            assessment.State
                                                                        });
    };
```

And here is an example the JSON this service call returns:

```
{"State":1}
```

Everything works fine until I try to Deserialize the JSON returned by the fake Nancy browser. First I tried to use the built in method provided by Nancy's `BrowserResponse.Body` object:

```
var result = (dynamic)response.Body.DeserializeJson<ExpandoObject>();
```

This deserializes to an empty object. Which is no good. However, if we use the Newtonsoft equivalent then everything is fine (almost).

```
var result = (dynamic) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(response.Body.AsString());
```

The JSON deserialization now works and so the following Shouldly assertion passes with flying colours:

```
((AssessmentState) result.State).ShouldBe(assessmentState);
```

However, for reasons that I suspect have to do with anonymous types, the following line fails at run-time (it compiles fine).

```
result.ShouldNotBe(null);
```

[image: Shouldly Exception]

That is quite a lot of information. Let me distil it down to two questions:

1. Why does Nancy's built in JSON deserializer not work given that the Newtonsoft version does?
2. How do I work with the dynamic types generated by the JSON de-serialisation so that the Shouldly extension methods do not cause a run-time exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer the first question, but WRT Shouldly and dynamic types, Shouldly's `ShouldNotBe` method is an extension method on `object`. The DLR doesn't allow you to call extension methods on objects typed as `dynamic` (hence the runtime binder exception you're seeing)

I'd suggest that if you want to call ShouldNotBe(null) on result, you'd have to cast it to an `object` first (ie: `((object)result).ShouldNotBe(null)`)

-x